# How to make double zero output?

Tags: countdown

I'm currently working with a countdown timer and am trying to make it so it would display '05', '00', etc. instead of '5', '0', etc. Any idea on how I would do this?

```
format: function(r){
var out="";
if(r.d != 0){out += (r.d<=9?'0':'')+r.d +" "+((r.d==1)?"":"")+" : ";}
if(r.h != 0){out += r.h +" "+((r.h==1)?"":"")+" : ";}
out += r.m +" "+((r.m==1)?"":"")+" : ";
out += r.s +" "+((r.s==1)?"":"")+" : ";
return out.substr(0,out.length-2);
```

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is Javascript.

How about

```
("0"+number).substring(-2)
```

This generalises to things other than 2-digit times, where just testing for <= 9 might be just as easy anyway, so for up to 6 digit numbers requiring leading zeroes:

```
("00000"+number).substring(-6)
```